# React Native Numeric Keyboard returnKeyType Label iOS

Tags: ios, reactjs, native

I try to add "done" button to iOS keyboard on my react native application.
When it is standard keyboard, "Done" label will change by language of the phone.
But when I use numeric keyboard, "Done" label not changing.

How can I change label of "Done" text on iOS?

Here is the example:

```
<TextInput keyboardType="numeric" returnKeyType="done" />
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include your code?

Comment: I added, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the "Done" button label according to the user's language by using the InputAccessoryView.

https://reactnative.dev/docs/inputaccessoryview